# Solving Robot Paths with Pascal's Triangle

Tags: javascript, algorithm, mathematics

I wanted to take on the challenge of the classic [Robot Path's problem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-possible-paths-top-left-bottom-right-nxm-matrix/) but solve it using Pascal's triangle.  The approach was generate pascal's triangle, then grab the middle element from the row. I saw the following pattern:

```
//where combos are on pascal's triangle:
// 1x1 grid on the 1st line ===> 1
// 2x2 grid on 3rd line==> 2
// 3x3 grid on 5th line ===> 6
// 4x4 grid on 7th line ===> 20
// 5x5 grid on the 9th line ===> 70
// 6 x6 on the 11th line ===> 252
```

and so made my getPaths() function accordingly:
     var tri = pascal(n * 2);

```
function getPaths(n) {

  if (n === 1) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (n === 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    var oddElement = (n + (n - 2));
    var mid = Math.floor(tri[oddElement].length / 2);
    // console.log(oddElement);
    return tri[oddElement][mid];
  }

}
```

Below is the entire function. what could I have done better?

```
    //Using pascal's triangle to get all unique paths on a board, where only moves are down and to the right:

//generate Pascal's triangle.
function pascal(n) {
  function pascalHelper(n, arr) {
    if (n < 2) {
      return arr;
    }
    var prevTier = arr[arr.length - 1];
    var currTier = [1];
    for (var i = 1; i < prevTier.length; i++) {
      currTier[i] = prevTier[i] + prevTier[i - 1];
    }
    currTier.push(1);
    arr.push(currTier);
    return pascalHelper(n - 1, arr);
  }
  return pascalHelper(n, [
    [1]
  ]);
}


function getPaths(n) {
var tri = pascal(n * 2);
  if (n === 1) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (n === 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    var oddElement = (n + (n - 2));
    var mid = Math.floor(tri[oddElement].length / 2);
    // console.log(oddElement);
    return tri[oddElement][mid];
  }

}
//observed pattern: triangle has to be twice as long as the number of paths.
console.log(getPaths(7));
//where combos are on pascal's triangle:
// 1x1 grid on the 1st line ===> 1
// 2x2 grid on 3rd line==> 2
// 3x3 grid on 5th line ===> 6
// 4x4 grid on 7th line ===> 20
// 5x5 grid on the 9th line ===> 70
// 6 x6 on the 11th line ===> 252
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collapse the two base cases (`n === 1` and `n === 0`) in `getPaths()` into one `n < 2` condition, which then also matches the base case used in `pascal()`.

Also Pascal's triangle only needs to be calculated if `n` is more than 1, so the call to `pascal()` can be put into the else-clause rather than at the beginning of the function.

```
function getPaths(n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return n;
    } else {
        var tri = pascal(n * 2);
        var oddElement = (n + (n - 2));
        var mid = Math.floor(tri[oddElement].length / 2);
        // console.log(oddElement);
        return tri[oddElement][mid];
    }
}
```